# reg expression with backslash and certain chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all escape characters returned from this steam json

```
tings_block\">\r\n\t\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right
```

i'm trying to pull out the \r and \n so i'm left with

```
tings_block"><div class="market_listing_right
```

When I try

```
[^\\r]
```

It pulls out the backslashes but it also pulls out all the other r's that aren't next to a backslash. How can I achieve this?

Comment: a character class is only a set of characters, not a place where you can put substrings. if you want a substring, write a substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
/(\\n)|(\\r)/
```

Which is \n OR \r

Comment: Yes, but why do you use capturing groups? And for which method is this pattern?

Comment: Not that familiar with javascript regex, **/\\n|\\r/** would work, but fails in shell eg. sed and awk context because **|** is  interpreted as a pipe.

Comment: In BRE indeed, but not in ERE (used by default in awk, used in sed with the -E (or -r in gnu) parameter). But It isn't the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

This would remove all `\r`, `\n`, `\t` and all simple `\` in your string.

```
var regex = /\\[rnt]?/g;
str.replace(regex, "");
```

Comment: Thanks  Casimir et Hippolyte :)